# defining part of a method in a parent class without defining the return

Tags: c#, inheritance

Can I have a base class with something similar to a virtual method that declares some partial functionality, but does not return anything, in such a way that inherited classes will execute that functionality and then proceed to return something?

Simplified example:

```
    class Parent
    {
        float baseFloat;  
        public virtual void MyMethod()
        {
            baseFloat = 3.14f;
        }
    }

    class Child : Parent
    {
        public override float MyMethod()
        {
            base.Method();
            return 6.28f;
        }
    }
```

Of course this will error because the overridden method has return type float vs void. The reason I want this is that I can be sure that all derived classes will want the analogous code to `baseFloat = 3.14f;` which modifies a class variable, but they will have their own implementations of `return 6.28f;`. So currently I am copy pasting the repeating code into all derived classes, but it would be nice to just implement that once in the base class.

Thanks

Comment: If you override a virtual method (using the `override` keyword), then it definitely must exactly match the signature of the method you are overriding.

Comment: The signature must be the same. You can declare the parent method `abstract`, if the class can be abstract too. Otherwise, you'd have to return some default value. Why not have the base method simply return `baseFloat`?

Comment: FYI, the `Math` library has a `PI` constant you can use (it's a `double`, though, not a `float`). For example: `double pi = Math.PI;`

Comment: You can choose a name other than "Method".

Comment: Forcing an inherited class to call an ancestor's methods is an anti-pattern  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super .   The act of calling the base method isn't the anti-pattern, but the requirement of calling the base method is.   What is the actual use case that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I take your point. I think it's time to rearchitect it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] in such a way that inherited classes will execute that functionality and then proceed to return something?

If you look at it the other way around, you could let the method in the parent class be non-virtual and return a `float`, and let that method return the value of a protected virtual property that every inheriting class overrides:

```
class Parent
{
    float baseFloat;
    
    protected virtual float MyMethodOutput => 0;

    public float MyMethod()
    {
        baseFloat = 3.14f;
        
        return MyMethodOutput;
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    protected override float MyMethodOutput => 6.28f;
}
```

```
var child = new Child();

Console.WriteLine(child.MyMethod());
```

will then print `6.28`.